# Crontab starts again before the process of conversion in ffmpeg ends (depending on time suppose /2 minutes) How to Control that?

Tags: bash, unix, ffmpeg, cron

I am running a bash .sh file every two minutes with crontab. the problem is that when crontab runs bash file the process of ffmpeg video conversion starts,the conversion time varies depending on length of videos, i have set the crontab to run every two minutes. crontab runs again after two minutes before end of ffmpeg conversion.

How to Figure out:

control of crontab and conversion process so the crontab doesn't starts again until process of conversion is not completed.

```
#!/bin/bash
# set PATH to check existance of video file in this directory
checkfiles=/home/webuser/public_html/shareportal/convert_Up_videos/*
checkforfiles=/home/webuser/public_html/shareportal/convert_Up_videos
movetodire=/home/webuser/public_html/shareportal/uploaded_videos/
conversionprocessdir=/home/webuser/public_html/shareportal/conversion_process/
movetoArchive=/home/webuser/public_html/shareportal/Video_Archive/
blockpath=/home/webuser/public_html/shareportal/block.txt
processid=/home/webuser/public_html/shareportal/processid.txt
#format of output video file
webm='webm'
if [ "$(ls -A $checkforfiles)" ]
then 
#check directory for files to convert
for f in $checkfiles
    do  
        fullfilename="$f"
        filename=$(basename "$f")
        filewithoutextforimage="${filename%.*}"
        nametofile=$filewithoutextforimage | cut -c1-10;
        echo $filewithoutextforimage | cut -c1-10 1> $blockpath 2>&1
    filewithoutext="${f%.*}"
    fileextention="${f##*.}"
    image_path='/home/webuser/public_html/shareportal/video_images/'$filewithoutextforimage'.png'
    outputfilename=$conversionprocessdir"$filewithoutextforimage.webm"
    #ffmpeg conversion process starts here
    if (ffmpeg -i "$f" "$outputfilename" 1>> $blockpath 2>&1) 
    then 
        #Extract Image of video file on provided time stamp
        if (ffmpeg -ss 00:00:06 -i "$f" -vframes:v 1 "$image_path") 
        then
            echo "Image Extracted"
        else
            echo "Could not Extract Image"
        fi
        echo "Video Converted";
    else
        echo "Could Not Convert Video"
    fi
    #conversion Ends!!
    mv "$outputfilename" $movetodire
    mv "$fullfilename" $movetoArchive
done
else
echo "File Not Found Directory is empty!!!-----"
fi
```

Comment: Make your script create and destroy a file containing it's PID, if the script starts and sees that both the file exists and the process with that PID exists, then abort mission.

Comment: i know about this suggestion and thank you for that but problem is How to do that? it might seems very easy but i am new to scripting with bash and all ,would be glad if you provide doing such stuff with script?

Comment: please learn to search here before asking questions. I searched for " if the script starts and sees that both the file exists and the process with that PID exists" and it returns 6 answers. The first looks like the place for you to start. In any case, Stackoverflow is about helping people fix their code, not spec and design it, so take a stab a solving your problem and then post a new Q with specific code and specific problems. Good luck.

Comment: AND, Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here.

Comment: @shellter  I know what is there on the link,pleas be more specific if there is problem with my question it's the site you ask what you don't know and it never says "ask question along with your code" you ask to seek help

Comment: and it shouldn't be repeated,Please!! if you are not helpful don't be dumbful

Comment: @ASahra : I don't find the other [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195268/crontab-starts-again-befor-the-process-of-conversion-in-ffmpeg-endsdepending-on#comment69590457_41195268) `dumbful`.  Indeed, it sheds some light on how to tackle the problem. Keeping that aside, you need to do some research on linux processes and how to manage them. Particularly `ps` command and `kill` command.

Comment: @ASahra . Somebody downvoted your question not because, it is not without effort, but little research is done from your part on how to tackle the issue which is how to prevent a process from starting if another instance of the same is already running. With some research, you can increase the chances of getting an answer here..

Answer (score 1):

I am having a bite anyway

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -f /path/to/script_name.pid ] && ps $(</path/to/script_name.pid) &>/dev/null && exit
#exit the script if script is already running
    echo $$ >/path/to/script_name.pid # if the script is not running write pid to file
# Do the ffmpeg conversion
rm /path/to/script_name.pid
```

Comment: Did you incorporate my answer to your code and if so what results?

Comment: I have got This:  Error :Process ID list syntax error.do i have to put it befor starting of the loop or inside the loop? if inside so where?

Comment: The first two lines just after the `shebang(#!/bin/bash)` and the last line at the end of the script. That said, you need to store the temporary pid file is a folder that is accessible and rename the `/path/to` part approporiately. Hope you've already done that.

Answer (score 1):

I have got my problem solved worked perfect,it might help somebody else so i am gonna put here.Thanks for great contribution of Big man @sjsam.
This is what i put on the start of my script ,it ensures that there is one instance of script running at the time using flock.

```
# stop on errors
set -e
scriptname=$(basename $0)
pidfile="/var/run/${scriptname}"

# lock it
exec 200>$pidfile
flock -n 200 || exit 1
pid=$$
echo $pid 1>&200

## Your code:
```

Source :[This guy](http://tobrunet.ch/2013/01/follow-up-bash-script-locking-with-flock/)

Comment: plus1 for this. It is a great feeling when you improvise perfectly to solve a problem.